# python plot multiple bar ranges with dates

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have this two dataframe:

```
x1=[{"dates":'2018-01-31',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-02-28',"rev":-5},
{"dates":'2018-03-31',"rev":-7},
{"dates":'2018-04-30',"rev":-8},
{"dates":'2018-05-31',"rev":-9},
{"dates":'2018-06-30',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-07-31',"rev":1},
{"dates":'2018-08-31',"rev":2},
{"dates":'2018-09-30',"rev":3},
{"dates":'2018-10-31',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-11-30',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-12-31',"rev":5}]


x2=[{"dates":'2018-01-31',"rev":-5},
{"dates":'2018-02-28',"rev":-9},
{"dates":'2018-03-31',"rev":-9},
{"dates":'2018-04-30',"rev":-6},
{"dates":'2018-05-31',"rev":-1},
{"dates":'2018-06-30',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-07-31',"rev":-14},
{"dates":'2018-08-31',"rev":2},
{"dates":'2018-09-30',"rev":3},
{"dates":'2018-10-31',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-11-30',"rev":-4},
{"dates":'2018-12-31',"rev":5}]


df1=pd.DataFrame(x1)
df1["dates"]=pd.to_datetime(df1.dates)
df2=pd.DataFrame(x2)
df2["dates"]=pd.to_datetime(df2.dates)
```

(Thanks [Flavio Moraes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14584908/flavio-moraes)
)

I would like to plot then as a bar plot. The matplotlib guide suggests to do something like the following:

```
width = 0.35  
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, y1, width, label='y1')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, y2, width, label='y2')
```

However, this seems to not working with dates. Indeed I have tried:

```
ax = plt.axes()
widthb = 10
rects1 = ax.bar(df1.dates - widthb/2, df1.rev,color='blue', width=widthb)
rects2 = ax.bar(df2.dates + widthb/2, df2.rev,color='red',  width=widthb)
ax.xaxis_date()
```

As expected, I get the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'float'
```

Do you have any suggestion to overcome this problem and simultaneously to have a beautiful plot?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use pandas's plotting methods, i.e. [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).

Comment: because pandas is not as customizable as matplolib.

Comment: You can create the `axes` and pass it to pandas though, let pandas do the lion's share of the plotting, then customize the output to your heart's content w/ matplotlib.

Comment: it's quite difficult to do that unless you do without some important feature of matplolib. For example I have named  a column as "ex_ax". Due to the fact that I would like to plot according to latex style (matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)), pandas was not able to handle it in plot.bar .

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `merge` and plot:

```
ax = df1.merge(df2, on='dates', how='outer').plot.bar(x='dates')
# other format with `ax`
ax.xaxis_date()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I will use this solution, although I prefer to plot with ax and matplolib features.

Comment: @diedro `ax` is a Matplotlib axis instance. You can do everything you would do with other axis instance. `ax.xaxis_date()` is an example.